# How to extract element from a numeric list which is contained in an array object

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I was trying to extract a data point from a cell in a pandas data frame, the data appears to be a list: [1,3,4,6...]. 
I want to use it as a list or numpy array.

I extracted this data by indexing this cell, and call the .values attribute. It returns as follows:

```
array([array([1,3,4,6...])], dtype = object)
```

Without calling .values, it would look like:

```
[1,3,4,6...]
Name: abc (name of columne), dtype: object
```

The size of this array is just 1.

I struggled to further extract the element from this array, or use it as an array with a size equal to the length of the list inside the array.

What I am expecting is just a simple list of `[1,3,4,6...]` .

Comment: need reproducible example code for solving problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Definitely gonna need some data from your dataframe in order to properly diagnose the issue and solve it. I don't want to guess or make assumptions that may or may not apply to your problem. But, since the "list" is not an accepted data structure in Pandas, those types are generally stored as objects or strings, and then you need to make a function that can parse and convert the type to a list for further use in Python.

Comment: Add `.squeeze().to list()`. `df` being your DataFrame, what is the output of `df.to_dict('tight')`? (Please [edit] the question to provide the output)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.